# Appending to char array with sprintf

Tags: c++, printf

So it is tempting to do this:

```
char buf[1024] = "this is";
std::sprintf(buf, "%s test", buf);
```

But it is undefined behaviour. I suppose it can be solved via temporary:

```
char buf[1024] = "this is";
std::sprintf(buf, "%s test", std::string(buf).c_str());
```

What are the downsides of this approach?

Comment: Alternatives: `strcpy` (in this case); `sprintf(buf + strlen(buf), " test");`.  You should also consider using the safer versions (`sprintf_s`).

Comment: This is C++, you should be using a `std::string` instead of a `char[]` to begin with: `string buf = "this is"; buf += " test";`

Comment: @RemyLebeau true, but for various reasons it has to be as presented in the example

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm `sprintf_s` is not any safer than `sprintf`, as well as not being widely supported. `snprintf` would be a better option

Comment: @M.M I meant `snprintf` but the wrong function name came to mind.  Sigh.

Answer (score 6):

To append a string to a char array use [strcat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat):

```
char buf[1024] = "this is";
std::strcat(buf, " test");
```

Comment: Why do you cast `" test"` to `char *`?

Comment: or `memmove (buf + strlen(buf), " test", sizeof " test");`